# I'm a rookie GM with rookie players using a published campaign. How do I let players run the campaign after narratives without stepping in?

Tags: dnd-5e, gm-techniques, published-adventures

The title mainly explains my situation. I'm using *The Dragon of Icespire Peak* campaign from the D&D Essentials Kit. I want to run as the GM, but am unsure of what to do if players don't know what to do after narratives are over and we're not in combat. **What can I do to help the players without them having to rely on me to tell them what to do in the future?**

Comment: Great question! I do think it's been asked before - does [this question on how to keep players aware of objectives](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/202704/how-to-help-my-players-keep-better-track-of-their-objectives) answer your need?

Comment: No. It's not that problem, but that problem may become an actual problem we face in the future.

Comment: My problem is I'm worried the players won't know what to do when I'm done with narratives. I would like to help them, but am unsure how to help without them relying on me to help them in the future.

Comment: What do you mean by "won't know what to do?" What do you expect/want to happen when you finish that? That goal will help clarify how we can focus an answer.

Comment: What I mean is that I'm worried the players won't know how to complete the goals in the dungeon without becoming immensely confused.

Comment: So you're looking to figure out how they should be aware and follow the objectives given in the narrative? :D

Comment: Yes, pretty much. Would that make this question a duplicate or simply have to be closed, or just answered with a simple answer?

Comment: It's a duplicate, and that's totally okay. People ask things in different ways, so this is another signpost for future users.

Comment: That's not really my question: I found. My players(now that I'm actually running a session are very unsure of what to do unless I offer suggestions(which they always take). How could I get them to progress without taking my suggestions all the time?

Comment: Can you explain why it’s a problem that you give your players options and they take them? That might help me understand if this isn’t a duplicate.